# Why there is only Raspbian in NOOBS 1.3.10?

Tags: raspbmc, noobs

I just downloaded current version of NOOBS (1.3.10) and there is only one operating system (Raspbian).

After zip file unpacking - I see that there os only Raspbian in `os` folder.

NOOBS 1.3.8 version was 1.4GB, current version is about 700MB.

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: It is meant to show a selection of operating systems.  If it didn't you need to raise an issue with http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/

Comment: @joan I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Oh dear.

It looks like this is done on purpose.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/releases/tag/v1.3.10

> **Minor release**
>
> NOOBS now only includes Raspbian by default, other distros can be
>   network-installed. This makes NOOBS usable on 4GB cards again (fixes #176 )

What a nonsense. If someone has 4GB card he can just remove folders from `os` folder after unzipping NOOBS.

Comment: *"What nonsense"* -> Not really.  You are failing to take into consideration that I may not want to download N GB that I'm then simply going to discard.  By your logic, we should install the entire repository of a distro (think terabytes, I dunno), then just uninstall all the things we don't want.  All that pointless waste of bandwidth costs both you and the people providing the servers.  Conversely, if you *do* want to use stuff, you *can* download it.  But +1 for providing the answer (and the question).

Comment: @goldilocks By nonsense I mean that "full" version contain less operating systems than "lite".

Comment: **No**, according to the online sources the 20 MB lite version contains *no* OS images, only the bootloader and installer.  You would need to install whatever you want via network.  So if you want raspbian, use the normal version.  If you don't want raspbian (and presumably want something else), then use the lite version and install whatever it is from there.  That minimizes transfer volume for everyone concerned.

Comment: @goldilocks My problem is that I'm using many RPi devices. Now I have to make network install many times and it does not minimize my transfer volume at all :)

Comment: I think they should make NOOBS modular, so everyone can download desired images in desired versions.